# vite creating project in Windows file instead of wsl

Tags: vite, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I run create `vite@latest` it creates the directory in a windows directory.

```
$ npm create vite@latest
'\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\alisson'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
```

Comment: run `which npm`

Comment: When I run `which npm` it shows: `/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm`

Comment: That’s why. It’s not the wsl/linux node install. Install that instead

Answer (score 0):

The WSL was trying to use the windows node, I just needed to install the node and NVM in the WSL and the problem was solved. Thanks Daniel